# iAd problems - Test ads working in iOS 4.1 simulator but not iOS4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

If I run my app in the 4.2 simulator I get the error:

```
Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x5b0c030 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}
```

BUT if I run the app in the 4.1 simulator I get the test ads as expected.

Does anyone have any ideas about what is going wrong? If it makes any difference I'm in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that everyone get the same error. (for iOS 4.2)

Apparently this is a bug on Apple's side.
I know for sure that a bug have been reported to their service.
Just have to wait for an answer.

However it also seems that when released, the App on iOS 4.2, doesn't have any problem and show iAds correctly.

Comment: I know that they should be working on the device but part of my problem is that after a week of the app being live I still have no requests in the "iAds Network" app in iTunesConnect